# Squish Qt version compatibility?

Tags: qt, squish

We just started writing automated test in Squish and the application we are testing will switch to a newer Qt version. I am not sure if we need to upgrade to another Squish version or not. 
Can anyone please tell me if the application changes to a newer Qt version, do we have to switch to a Squish version that is built for the corresponding or newer Qt version, too?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Depends from which version to which you switch. In general, your application's Qt version should be binary compatible with the Qt version Squish built with. But if your update from Qt 4.6 to 4.8, you probably don't need to update Squish.

Comment: @vahancho, such version differences are generally not supported. It may work, sometimes for a while or for some things done in the test script or AUT, but that is luck more than anything.

Answer (score 0):

A Squish for Qt binary package must match the Qt configuration and Qt (major and minor) version (as well as operating system, architecture) of the Qt used by the Application Under Test (AUT). A mismatch on these attributes is generally not supported (except for specific cases mentioned by Squish technical support).

Comment: So, patch version can differ?

Comment: Yes, the patch version can differ. Squish for Qt installers do not specify the patch level version anyway, which is another indication for this.